# Change A Link To A Button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this link - but I want to turn it into a button in rails 3?

```
<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [button-styled link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406702/link-to-not-formatting-button/4406740#4406740).

```
<%= link_to 'New_Article', {:controller => "articles", :action => "new"}, {"data-icon" => "button", "data-theme" => "a"} %>
```

Or, as @Zabba points out, use the [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper.

```
<%= button_to 'New Article', {:controller => "articles", :action => "new"} %>
```

Comment: And if OP really wanted to change/update something at server-side, then the [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper would be more appropriate.

Comment: @zabba @mattball Okay this brings the user to the right page - however it's still a link and not a button   <%= link_to 'New Article', {:controller => "articles", :action => "new"}, {"data-icon" => "button", "data-theme" => "a"} %>

Comment: @user, the question I linked to uses jQuery Mobile, which is why `{"data-icon" => "button", "data-theme" => "a"}` styles the link as a button. jQuery Mobile does the work of turning `<a href="..." data-icon="button" data-theme="a">` into an element that looks like a button. Short answer: you need some custom CSS if you stick with `link_to`, or you can just use `button_to`.

Comment: @mattball @zabba Its not working....   Routing Error - No route matches "/articles/new" on a blank page? It's strange though because the link and button both work and have the exact same URL http://localhost:3000/articles/new but only the link shows the actual 'new article' page!?!!

Comment: @ubique, take a look at the log. You will probably see that clicking the link is doing a `GET` for `new_article_path`. Clicking the button is doing a `POST` to `new_article_path`. Please go through the Ruby on Rails guides.

Comment: Yeah been reading and reading around this and getting nowhere! Any clues on how to do it?